# RecyclerView not scrolling smothly

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

Recyclerview is not scrolling smoothly with scrollview. If i remove scrollview than its smooth. What should i do for smooth scroll of recyclerview?

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <ScrollView
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/content_activity_main"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            >

            <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
                android:id="@+id/rv"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                />

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/ll"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="90dp"
                android:layout_below="@+id/rv"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="50dp"
                    android:layout_height="50dp"
                    android:scaleType="fitXY"
                    />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textView35"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                    />

            </LinearLayout>
        </RelativeLayout>
    </ScrollView>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should not put your RecyclerView inside a ScrollView. If you need to show a footer at the end of your RecyclerView (i.e. a view after the last item of your RecyclerView) then this should also be part of the RecyclerView. To do this, you just need to specify a different item type in your adapter and return the appropriate ViewHolder.

First add this in your adapter:

```
private class ViewType {
      public static final int NORMAL = 0;
      public static final int FOOTER = 1;
}
```

Then, override the getCount() of your adapter and add one more item:

```
@Override
public int getCount() {
    return yourListsSize + 1;
}
```

Next, you need to specify of which type is the current item. To achieve this, override the getItemViewType() of your adapter:

```
@Override
public int getItemViewType(int position) {
    if(position == getCount() - 1)
        return ViewType.FOOTER;
    else
        return ViewType.NORMAL;
}
```

Finally, in the onCreateViewHolder() check the type of the current item and inflate the appropriate view:

```
@Override
public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup viewGroup, int viewType) {

    View rowView;

    switch (viewType) {
        case ViewType.NORMAL:
            rowView=LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.normal, viewGroup, false);
            break;
        case ViewType.FOOTER:
            rowView=LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.footer, viewGroup, false);
            break;
        default:
            rowView=LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.normal, viewGroup, false);
            break;
    }
    return new ViewHolder(rowView);
}
```

Of course, you would also need to move your footer layout in a separate xml file in order to inflate it here. By "footer layout", I'm referring to your `LinearLayout` with `android:id="@+id/ll"` and its child views.

Hope this helps.